# Периодично возникающий сбой

Tags: android, аудио, mediaplayer

В простом приложении при нажатии на кнопку с правильным ответом на вопрос воспроизводиться мелодия (использую метод start() класса MediaPlayer). 
Проходит так несколько вопросов и звук перестает воспроизводиться. 
Закрываю приложение, открываю снова - все по новой работает нормально (до поры, до времени).

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Добавьте код. У вас может быть как ошибка в управлении состоянием медиа плеера, так и просто какая-нибудь ошибка в другом месте, связанная, например, с работой в нескольких потоках.

Comment: Ну и выхлоп adb logcat тоже полезен будет